# How to remove a dead service in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, services

I would like to cleanup a windows service leftover from an application that I uninstalled.  The executable for it has been removed, but it is still visible in the services view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At a command prompt:

> sc delete SERVICENAME

See Source: [How To Unregister Windows Services](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2008/02/14/how-to-unregister-windows-service.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, nice. I've always done it the slow, manual way via the Registry, but if this works I won't even bother answering with *that* disaster-waiting-to-happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried the above and it didn't appear to work even though you are positive you typed everything correctly try the following command:

`sc query state= all >> "C:\\[Preferred Foldername]\Service_details.LOG"`

I found when running the above that, even though the Windows Services MMC showed that the name of the service was one thing, when i piped it to a log file it showed it as another.

Basically, because there was a space in the name, Windwos truncated it to remove the space.  So even though it displayed with a space in the Services MMC, in realterms, there shouldn't have been one.

After the above discovery I found that the suggested routine worked a treat!

Thanks for that one Will